JS - many setTimeout takes longer than expected
I'm working on some projects and I was wondering why the setTimeout(s) I was delaying where taking a lot longer then expected...
To give a context, the code reacts to some triggers, and the function fires quite a lot (maybe like 15 times a second). on this function, I increment a global value, then do a setTimeout of 3 seconds and decrement the global value by the same amount (expecting it to be back to 0 after the maximum 3 seconds every timeout should take)
But apparently they have a way of working different from what I expected, and they sort of stack in time... so the global value decrement slowly.
code :

//trigger method... just fires like a button press in html
register("soundPlay", () => {
    addCount();
}).setCriteria("random.successful_hit");

var count = 0;

function addCount() {
    console.log("triggered");
    count+= 10;
    setTimeout(function () {
        count-= 10;
    }, 3000);
}

Here's a result of the function after I stop triggering, the stacking is shown in the brackets. It shows every 1/20th of a second. So from the moment I stop it takes over 30 seconds to get down to zero.

Any ideas why? Any solutions or reason?
Ty :)

What is this font called? O, this is a minecraft mod I guess

Read about event loop in JS. Should help.

Its working for me... after 3 seconds it stops at 0

What is the expected behaviour?

@Nonemoticoner I know how JS works (one thread, and so on). I was wondering if the problem was not from setTimeout itself... looking at Pipe message it looks like no tho

You have to use debounce to get the effect you want


var count = 0;

b.onclick = addCount

const clearCount = debounce(() => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    count = 0;
    console.log(count)
  }, 3000);
}, 500)

function addCount() {
  count += 10;
  console.log(count)
  clearCount()
}

function debounce(callback, wait) {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
<button id="b">add count</button>




I don't want it to be reset to zero 3 seconds after the last update but for it to update accordingly to each trigger. so going up, and going down as every trigger arrive at 3 seconds

@Ren your code works like that right now without any changes. You should describe how the current version differs from what you expect

I don't get it... you can only have one setTimeout running at once ? because right now it is going up 0 ->10 -> 20 -> 30 and then down 30 -> 20 -> 10 -> 0 on my code (the problem beeing it takes longer than expected). And not really hard reset at any time like yours do

If I was not clear enought I do want the trigger to fire every time (so around 15 times a second). My problem beeing that the time it takes to get back to zero is long, where it should decay on the course of 3 seconds

Your code works fine for me

It adds 10 to count every 100ms (1s overall)
It waits 3 seconds since the start (so 2s after the last one)
It subtracts 10 from count every 100ms (1s overall)



var count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  setTimeout(addCount, i * 100)
}

function addCount() {
    count+= 10;
    console.log(count)
    setTimeout(function () {
        count-= 10;
        console.log(count)
    }, 3000);
}



